# Automatically add reviewers in github alongside users from CODEOWNERS

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I have a repo in github, and it has a CODEOWNERS specified, and a branch rule that requires PR approval from a code owner before merging. Wonderful.

However I want other members of the team to also be added as reviewers automatically, even though their approval doesn't count for the merge check. It's still good for them to see the PR and comment / enquire.

ChatGPT tells me to do this with a Github Action like so:

```
name: Add Default Reviewers
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
jobs:
  add-reviewers:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Get Pull Request Number
        id: pr_number
        run: echo "PR_NUMBER=${{ github.event.number }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Add Default Reviewers
        run: |
          curl -X POST \
          -H "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.YOUR_GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
          -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
          https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/pulls/${{ env.PR_NUMBER }}/requested_reviewers \
          -d '{
            "reviewers": ["reviewer1", "reviewer2"],
            "team_reviewers": []
          }'
```

Would this be the most sensible way to achieve such a requirement?

Comment: I know about [this action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/add-reviewers) which could be useful in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a related service called [Friendly Fire](https://friendlyfire.tech/), which is designed to solve the problem CODEOWNERS *sort of* attempts to solve.

You can add GitHub reviewers to a repo, define path patterns, and it will assign reviewers in round-robin fashion.

The added benefit is that you can connect GitHub users to their Slack handles, enabling direct Slack notifications and individual reminders. Friendly Fire will also NOT assign users who are out sick or on vacation in Slack (or whatever user emojis you configure for that).

I go more into the CODEOWNERS problem [here](https://friendlyfire.tech/docs#codeowners).